# Controller spec and default_url_options

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm using Rails 3.1.3 with rspec-rails 2.8.1. I have a scope ':locale'
in routes.rb and I want to run controller and routing
specs. I'm aware of the problem with setting default_url_options in
application.rb controller so I apply the solution found in the last
comment on rspec issue #255 (
https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/issues/255
)

```
#./spec/support/default_locale.rb
class ActionView::TestCase::TestController
  def default_url_options(options={})
    { :locale => I18n.default_locale }
  end
end

class ActionDispatch::Routing::RouteSet
  def default_url_options(options={})
    { :locale => I18n.default_locale }
  end
end

#./spec/controllers/categories_controller_spec.rb
require "spec_helper"

describe CategoriesController do

  describe "GET index" do
    it "assigns all categories as @categories" do
      category = Factory :category

      get :index
      assigns(:categories).to_a.should eq([category])
    end
  end
end
```

This test fails with routing error but if I use "get :index,
locale: :fr" instead of just "get :index" the test pass.
This test is a example of controller spec but I have failing tests for
routing and request. (I have no view specs but
I'm pretty sure they would also fail)

I can't figure out where the problem come from and why the patch
doesn't solve it. Is there another thing to do ? (I just put the code
in ./spec/support/default_locale.rb and verify that it loads
correctly).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This code injects the locale in the controller's
params (which makes all my controller specs pass without explicitly
specifying the locale in each controller spec):

```
class ActionController::TestCase
  module Behavior
    def process_with_default_locale(action, parameters = nil, session =
nil, flash = nil, http_method = 'GET')
      parameters = { :locale => I18n.default_locale }.merge( parameters
|| {} )
      process_without_default_locale(action, parameters, session, flash,
http_method)
    end
    alias_method_chain :process, :default_locale
  end
end
```

And here is the "cheat" I use to inject the locale in Rails's
assert_recognizes method (which makes all my routing specs pass without
explicitly specifying the locale in each routing spec):

```
module ActionDispatch::Assertions::RoutingAssertions
  def assert_recognizes_with_default_locale(expected_options, path,
extras={}, message=nil)
    expected_options = { :locale => I18n.default_locale.to_s
}.merge(expected_options || {} )
    assert_recognizes_without_default_locale(expected_options, path,
extras, message)
  end
  alias_method_chain :assert_recognizes, :default_locale
end
```

Stucking those two code snippets in my spec helper class means that I do
not need to change all my previous controller/routing specs during the
implementation of supporting multiple locales for my app.

Hope this helps,